# cfldap useTLS failing and providing no information why it is failing

Tags: coldfusion, lucee

I am trying to use `useTLS="true"` with cfldap but the error i am getting is not very helpful. It just says error connecting to ldap server.

no logs and nothing, I am using CF2021.

This is my first time using `cfldap` and i am not sure what needs to be done to fix this issue. if i do not use `useTLS`, the cfldap is connected successfully.

any clue what could be going wrong here.

Comment: What do you mean with *error i am getting is not very helpful*? Can you post the error message? Do you wrap the CFLDAP tag within CFTRY/CFCATCH? An error message may look like *error 49, data 52e*. Looks strange but says something.

Comment: And you've tried from a different LDAP client with the same settings, with the same access, and it was fine? If the LDAP server does indeed support connections via TLS... is it using the same version as the CF server is?

Answer (score 0):

You may have to specify `port="636"`, or some other port, depending on the LDAP server configuration.